# Remove items from one array which are present in another array?

Tags: arrays, bash

I am downloading a list of files, however I want to optimize so it doesn't go to download if its already downloaded. I thought about creating an array with `myfiles=$(ls *.jpg)`; and then excluding those files from a my list of files `myDownload=$(cat SiteFiles.txt)`. Eventually need to remove the items from **myfiles** from **myDownload**. I wonder if this is possible at all and if there can be issues like not being smart enough. For example [ a b c d ] not finding b on a secondary array like [ 1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d ] because the arrays didn't match the sequential order.

Comment: The statement `myfiles=$(ls *.jpg)` doesn't create an array, i.e. a variable accessed by an index, but it creates a string where the elements are separated by a `\n` char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another variant

```
myfiles=( $(ls *.jpg) ) # add files to an array
myDownload=$(cat SiteFiles.txt) # add list to a var
# remove existing file from download list if exist
for item in "${myfiles[@]}"; { myDownload=${myDownload//$item/}; }
echo $myDownload
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
declare -A ihaveit      # create an associative array
for f in *.jpg; do
    (( ihaveit[$f]++ )) # set a mark for files at hand
done

while read -r f; do
    [[ -z ${ihaveit[$f]} ]] && myDownload+=("$f")
                        # if the file in the SiteFiles.txt is not in my list
                        # then append it to the download list
done < SiteFiles.txt

echo "${myDownload[@]}" # see the result
```

If you prefer a one liner and the filenames do not contain newlines, you can also say something like:

```
comm -2 -3 <(sort SiteFiles.txt) <(ls -1 *.jpg | sort)
```

Note that parsing the output of `ls` is supposed to be an antipattern in general and I don't recommend to use the latter.